# drush requires civicrm to be enabled when installing in saltstack

Tags: drupal, drush

I am trying to use saltstack to provision a centos 6.7 system that has drupal and civicrm. I have civicrm as a tar ball that I extract into `sites/all/modules` before trying to install. I am able to do all the provisioning without problem until I need to install civicrm with drush by running:

```
drush civicrm-install
```

This command works perfectly fine when I ssh into the target machine and execute it directly in the shell, but when the command is executed through saltstack I get this error message:

```
Command civicrm-install needs the following module(s) enabled to run: civicrm.
The drush command 'civicrm-install' could not be executed.
```

I have already tried clearing the drush cache using `drush cc`, I have tried putting the command in a bash script and running the bash script from salt, and I have already placed `civicrm.drush.inc` in `~/.drush` with no luck. Can somebody tell me what drush is missing from the environment in order to execute correctly?

[edit] More detail on what I have already tried for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that when running in saltstack drush can't resolve the right environment variables to find ~/.drush. I put civicrm.drush.inc in my drush/commands directory and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behaviour occasionally on CiviCRM sites where CiviCRM is already installed, and it frequently clears up by use of `drush cc drush` or `drush rr` ([registry-rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)).

If you're installing CiviCRM on a "fresh" Drupal site, the Drush commands may not be available until the module is enabled as you say. In that case you might need to install CiviCRM's Drush additions to `~/.drush/` or the commands directory of your installed Drush codebase (eg `/usr/local/src/drush/commands`).

Worth a look into how [Provision CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/provision_civicrm) handles this as well, since it's certainly capable of installing CiviCRM via Drush.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried drush cc and have placed civicrm.drush.inc in ~/.drush. Unfortunately constraints in my deployment environment do not let me use anything other than saltstack.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Drush were you using? It did not work for me with 7.x.dev but but did with 8.1.0.

I also passed the following parameter to drush `--include=/var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/drush` which meant that I didn't have to

> [...] put civicrm.drush.inc in my drush/commands directory

as you mentioned that you had to in your answer.

**Note:** the --include option to drush expects the directory containing the configuration file, not the configuration file itself.